# include .php file in folder above

Tags: php

I am receiving this error

```
Warning: include(../config.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/soizastu/public_html/cms/happy-api/retrieve.php on line 2

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '../config.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/soizastu/public_html/cms/happy-api/retrieve.php on line 2

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'soizastu'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/soizastu/public_html/cms/happy-api/retrieve.php on line 6
Error connecting to database.
```

basically in the cms folder is config.php i thought `include "../config.php";` would do the trick but it dosent appear so.

Comment: I suppose your config.php file necessary for you to connect to your database. If this is the case, you should consider using `require()` instead of `include()`. It does the same thing as include, but it stops the script with a fatal error in case of failure.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try computing the absolute path and including that.

```
include(dirname(__FILE__)."/../config.php");
```

I think it's the safest bet when dealing with multiple levels of include.

Comment: I think that's the correct approach. Also, can do include(dirname(dirname(\__FILE\__)).'/config.php');

Comment: @Ben You probably meant `dirname(dirname(__FILE__).'/../');`.

Comment: i believe its including it but i cannot access the strings within it :S

Comment: @user393272 If you get `[function.include]: failed to open stream` then it isn't including it. To test inclusions you can add echo lines in the files you included to see if the script passes through them.

Comment: @Alin. No, I meant what I wrote. Try it, it's equivalent to your answer. dirname basically takes out the last part of a path (even if it's a directory already), so the second dirname effectively move the path up one level.

Comment: I have added echo "$dbHost"; and no it has failed to echo it

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the user you're using to run your web server can read the file. For a sanity check, chmod the file to 665. If it's a Windows system, then make it so that Everyone can read the file.

Answer (score 0):

This should work `include('../config.php');`

Comment: didn't work for me either.i had to put dirname(__FILE__). to retrieve the absolute path.

Comment: Yes it should but its not working for CI (CodeIgniter)

Answer (score 0):

Just define the absolute path for the cms folder, in this case if the caller script (which you try to include the `config.php`) `/home/soizastu/public_html/cms/happy-api/retrieve.php`. Then write on top line of `retrieve.php` :

`define('ABSPATH',dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/');`

and include the `config.php` by write :

`require(ABSPATH . 'config.php');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code i hope it works for me

Assume we had dbconfig.php in home directory and include that file in file that inside home like path structure.
        |--admin
            |--includes
                |--add_dbconfig.php
        |--dbconfig.php

add_dbconfig.php

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZI7WC.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwB1z.png)