# php execution quits at specific line

Tags: php, mysql, debugging, mysqli

I am making a simple website. My site quits when I create a reference to another class.

```
$get_car_list = new GetCarList();
$car_list = $get_car_list->getEntireInventory();
```

It quits immediately upon the debugger hitting `$get_car_list = new GetCarList();`.

The code for the class I am referencing is as follows.

```
class GetCarList {

    public function getEntireInventory() {

        $car_list = array();

        // Connecting, selecting database
        $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost:8889', 'root', 'root')
        or die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());


        $queryStatementForIdList = "SELECT id FROM cars";

        $r = mysqli_query($connection, $queryStatementForIdList);

        $idList = mysqli_fetch_array($r);

        for($i = 1; $i < sizeof($idList); $i++) {
            $queryStatementForSingleCar = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE id = " . $idList[$i];
            $b = mysqli_query($connection, $queryStatementForSingleCar);
            $carInfo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($b);
            $thisCar = new Car($carInfo['id'], $carInfo['make'], $carInfo['model'], $carInfo['year'], $carInfo['thumbnail'],
                $carInfo['photos'], $carInfo['miles'], $carInfo['price']);
            array_push($car_list, $thisCar);
        }

        return $car_list;

    }

}
```

I am really new to php so it could be something extremely simple. But I found it a little strange because the debugger and execution completely quits upon a certain line of code.

EDIT: Here is the log printout from the event

```
[25-Feb-2015 04:28:27 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  include(../model/GetCarList.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dushanemotors/controller/InventoryController.php on line 12
[25-Feb-2015 04:28:27 Europe/Berlin] PHP Stack trace:
[25-Feb-2015 04:28:27 Europe/Berlin] PHP   1. {main}() /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dushanemotors/inventory.php:0
[25-Feb-2015 04:28:27 Europe/Berlin] PHP   2. InventoryController->__construct($url = *uninitialized*) /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dushanemotors/inventory.php:11
[25-Feb-2015 04:28:27 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '../model/GetCarList.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/lib/php') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dushanemotors/controller/InventoryController.php on line 12
[25-Feb-2015 04:28:27 Europe/Berlin] PHP Stack trace:
[25-Feb-2015 04:28:27 Europe/Berlin] PHP   1. {main}() /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dushanemotors/inventory.php:0
[25-Feb-2015 04:28:27 Europe/Berlin] PHP   2. InventoryController->__construct($url = *uninitialized*) /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dushanemotors/inventory.php:11
```

Comment: Are you including the file somewhere or using an autoloader to ensure the class is loaded on demand?  The error you are describing is most likely from the class being referenced but it cannot be found, you could confirm that this is the error by looking in the php log file.

Comment: I added the log printout. I think your right

Comment: @ryan4888; the error tells what you need to do

Comment: @ryan4888 While Oli is right, it does tell you what to add "include(../model/GetCarList.php);" to fix this error, you are just going to run into it again when you hit the line where you instantiate the "Car" object.  You should implement an autoloader for your project. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: you can include it just like in this link. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4281232/3580274

Comment: Warnings don't halt execution.  There has to be more to the error log.

Comment: what framework do you use???

Answer (score 0):

I was doing

```
include '../model/file.php';
```

when I should have done

```
include 'model/file.php';
```

For some reason my IDE (PhpStorm) was telling me the file did not exist. It is still throwing a warning for some odd reason.

Answer (score 0):

1st of all turn on all errors in :

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); // check your php.ini
$get_car_list = new GetCarList();
$car_list = $get_car_list->getEntireInventory();
```

2. Do you have `include` somewhere before you call `new GetCarList();`?
   Or do you have class declaration before this line?
3. Try to go step by step. So First iteration is to create one file with following code:

> ```
> error_reporting(E_ALL);
>
> ini_set('display_errors', 1); // check your php.ini
>
> class GetCarList {
>   public function getEntireInventory() {
>       return 'GetCarList Response';
>   }
> }
>
> $get_car_list = new GetCarList();
> $car_list = $get_car_list->getEntireInventory();
> echo $car_list;
> ```

So if it works you can start manipulate with your method `getEntireInventory()` which is bad so try to (but remember you are trying to create `Car` here - I have no idea where did you declare that class?):

```
public function getEntireInventory() {
        $car_list = array();

        $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost:8889', 'root', 'root')
        or die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());

       $query = "SELECT * FROM cars ";
       $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
       while ($carInfo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $thisCar = new Car($carInfo['id'], $carInfo['make'], $carInfo['model'], $carInfo['year'], $carInfo['thumbnail'],
                $carInfo['photos'], $carInfo['miles'], $carInfo['price']);
            array_push($car_list, $thisCar);
        }
        return $car_list;
}
```